# What is the purpose of putting 'de' before 'être' in: ...et d'être avec eux c'est plus important que la nourriture que je mange

Tags: grammaire, verbes, articles

Why does the article 'de' mean here? And what's the purpose of putting it behind 'être'?

> *Mais ce que j'aime le plus, c'est que je suis avec mes copains et **d'être** avec eux c'est plus important que la nourriture que je mange.*

I believe the last sentence can be translated as:
***... And being with them is more important than the food I eat.***

Comment: Une espèce de lapsus: et **le fait d'être avec eux** In speech, people often leave things out or put things in. Spoken language is full of imperfections or truncated expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***De*** is not an article but a preposition introducing the infinitive, a little like **to** in English.
A literal translation would be:

> **To** be with them, that's more important than the food I eat.

This ordering goal is to emphasize "to be with them". A non emphasized sentence would be :

> *[...] et c'est plus important **d'être avec eux** que la nourriture que je mange.*

While the sentence as a whole is casual, this particular usage is not a mistake or "imperfect French". *[Au contraire](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/192867/14014)*, it is even described as being literary by the [TLFi.](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/de)

> [**De**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/de)
> ...
> **II.** − De marque une relation syntaxique; il est introducteur de substantif, de pronom ou d'infinitif en fonction de complément, de sujet, d'attribut, d'apposition, ou en fonction expressive.
> ...
> **B. −** [*De* introducteur de sujet, d'attributs, d'apposition; *de* signifie « le fait de », en parlant d'un fait particulier.]
> **1. De** + infinitif sujet [(tour littéraire assez répandu; *de* a une valeur expressive plutôt que syntaxique).]
> **a)** [En tête de phrase.] *d'écrire ces quelques lignes, − de prendre date vis-à-vis de moi-même m'a fait grand bien* (Du Bos, Journal, 1924, p. 152).

The *[Littré](https://www.littre.org/definition/de)* shows a few quotes with this usage:

> *De dire si la compagnie Prit goût à la plaisanterie, J'en doute,* La Fontaine, *Filles de Minée*.
> *D'expliquer ce qui s'y passe, ce n'en est pas ici le lieu*, Bossuet, *Or. 7*
> *De savoir quelles sont leurs limites, ce n'est pas une chose facile*, La Bruyère, *VII*
> *De préférer la raison à la félicité, c'est être très insensé*, Voltaire, *Bramin*.

and states:

> Cette tournure est perpétuelle dans le XVII<sup>e</sup> siècle, et on ne parle guère autrement ; aujourd'hui on supprime souvent, surtout quand l'infinitif est sujet complexe, ce de qui n'est ni sans utilité ni sans grâce, et qui d'ailleurs peut être repris, quand on veut, d'après les meilleures et les plus sûres autorités.